# Using comma to separate List values in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to separate a list in Razor by `","` but I don't want the `","` at the end. I try to use `String.join` but nothing is happening.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (Language language in Model.apiAgent.languages)
{   
    @(string.Join(",", language.language));
}
```

it is still shows as

> EnglishSpanish

Comment: [msdn-docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) aren't that aweful anymore ;)
String.Join(String, String[])
You need to use your List/Array/Collection as second param.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're joining everything into one string, you don't need the loop. Just use

```
@(string.Join(",", Model.apiAgent.languages));
```

If the elements contained in `languages` aren't the strings you want, you may need to tease out the property you want with [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, if each element has a `language` property that you want to output, you can use:

```
@(string.Join(",", Model.apiAgent.languages.Select( l => l.language )));
```

Comment: without the loop? when I use this, this will print: Mvc.Models.AgentModels.api_Agent+Language,Mvc.Models.AgentModels.api_Agent+Language;

Comment: I see, you need to get the `language` property of each element in the `languages` list. Is that right? Edited my naswer.

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to tell based off of your question as you provide no real insight into what your model looks like. My guess is that this is what you are looking for though

```
string.Join(",", Model.apiAgent.languages)
```